# Azure Load Balancer with multiple IP - Outbound IP

Tags: routing, ip, load-balancing, azure

I have an Azure Load Balancer with 2 public IP addresses. One of them is used for public/application access, with LB rules (call it IP1)  and the other one for an administation access with LB and NAT rules (call it IP2).

When I send a curl command to determined my outbound IP address, the anwser is always the IP2. I haven't found any priority or settings option for the outbound flow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where a load balancer is configured with multiple IP's any of these can be used for the outbound IP and it is not possible to configure which.

See here for details - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#limitations

Comment: I went to this page almost 2 times, but not reading the #limitations. Feel really dumb. Thank you and sorry.